# How does GLEW work?

Tags: opengl, glew

I am currently learning OpenGL on Windows, and there is something I don't understand. If I want to call a function like `glShaderSource`, it's undefined unless I link GLEW. However, once I link GLEW and call `glewInit`, `glShaderSource` is suddenly defined and available to use. What kinds of functions do I need to explicitly load with GLEW, and what ones are automatically loaded in once I initialize GLEW?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The whole point of GLEW is that you *don't* need to ["explicitly load" functions](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions). If you wanted to explicitly load things, you wouldn't be using an [OpenGL Loading Library.](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) ;)

By initializing GLEW, you're telling it to load all OpenGL functionality (that it knows about) that your implementation provides. You can check the version numbers or extensions to see what was actually loaded. But once GLEW is initialized, it's loaded. Period.